# Connecting two recordsets with a foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small social network site which allows users to make comments on posts. I can display records based on the friends users have added using SQL. However, I want the comment made on each post to be shown directly below the post.

Post table:

```
all_id(PK), name, comment, time, expand
```

Comments table:

```
post_id, name, comment, all_id(FK)
```

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of Facebook: commenting on a post and seeing the post right below it. I have tried using a complex SQL join but it didn't show any data.

Comment: Less chat, more facts, more examples please. And use the `code block` feature in the editor.

Comment: What was the JOIN command that you tried to use?

Comment: What sort of database server are you using? PostgreSQL? MySQL? Microsoft MSSQL Server? SQL Lite? Also, what language are you programming this in? Python? PHP? Java? Ruby?

Comment: @JoshuaBurns - Judging by the tags, I'd say PHP and MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you could grab the post and all comments in a single query, the result set may be un-foreseeably large, in which case you may exhaust your database's, your script's or your server's memory. But if you wish to do so, let me know and I can post an example.

Alternately, you could use two separate queries. The first would grab the post, the second would grab all comments relating to that post.  Here is an example using PHP and mySQL:

```
// Connect to MySQL Database
$db = mysql_connect('my_host', 'my_username', 'my_password');
mysql_select_database('my_database', $db);
// Query for Posts from a specific user.
$grabPost = mysq_query("SELECT all_id, name, comment, time, expand FROM posts WHERE name = 'some_user_name'", $db);
// Iterate over each post
while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($grabPost)) {
    print '<b>' . htmlentities($post['name']) . '</b> - <i>' . $post['time'] . '</i><br />';
    print htmlentities($post['comment']);
    print '<br />';
    // Query for Comments relating to this Post
    $grabComments = mysql_query("SELECT post_id, name, comment FROM comments WHERE all_id = " . $post['all_id'], $db);
    // Iterate over each comment
    while($comment = mysql_fetch_assoc($grabComments)) {
        print '<p><b>' . htmlentities($comment['name']) . '</b> Says: ' . htmlentities($comment['comment']) . '</p>';
    }
    print '<hr />';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you replies@Joshua Burns...i use php mysql

Comment: Does the above solution take care of your problem, or are you interested in grabbing all comments with the post? Please keep in mind that could bomb your database or web server or PHP script!

Comment: thank you for you reply....am gonna try the one you gave me...would reply shortly...

Comment: hey thanks....i use dreamweaver cs5...and its saying there is a syntax error on line 8..i.e where the while starts from

Comment: I don't see a problem with grabbing the post and its comments in a single query - in fact I'd recommend this in almost ANY case. You'd just want to limit the amount of comments you grab at once (say, the 10 most recent). That said, read up on how a `left outer join` works. That's what you'd probably want to use to grab a post along with all its comments (even if it has no comments).

Comment: that's not how joining works, what he needs to use is a sub-query. joining returns one row per match, so one post with 10 comments would return ten rows.

Comment: sorry, was missing a parentheses. fixed.

Comment: did you replace some_user_name with a real user?